# count of nulls over a window

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to get the count of nulls group by ID but excluding the month and sales in group by

sample data

```
 id     custname    reportdate   sales
 1        xx        31-JAN-17    1256
 1        xx        31-MAR-17    <null>
 1        xx        30-JUN-17    5678
 1        xx        31-DEC-17    <null>
 1        xx        31-JAN-18    1222
 1        xx        31-MAR-18    <null>
 1        xx        30-JUN-18    5667
 1        xx        31-DEC-18    7890
 2        yy        31-JAN-17    1223
 2        yy        31-APR-17    3435
 2        yy        30-JUN-17    <null>
 2        yy        31-DEC-17    4567
 2        yy        31-JAN-18    5678
 2        yy        31-APR-18    <null>
 2        yy        30-JUN-18    <null>
 2        yy        31-DEC-18    2345
```

what i need as a output

```
 id     custname    reportdate   sales  count(Sales nulls)
 1        xx        31-JAN-17    1256     2
 1        xx        31-MAR-17    <null>   2
 1        xx        30-JUN-17    5678     2
 1        xx        31-DEC-17    <null>   2
 1        xx        31-JAN-18    1222     1
 1        xx        31-MAR-18    <null>   1
 1        xx        30-JUN-18    5667     1
 1        xx        31-DEC-18    7890     1
 2        yy        31-JAN-17    1223     1
 2        yy        31-APR-17    3435     1 
 2        yy        30-JUN-17    <null>   1 
 2        yy        31-DEC-17    9643     1
 2        yy        31-JAN-18    5678     2
 2        yy        31-APR-18    <null>   2
 2        yy        30-JUN-18    <null>   2
 2        yy        31-DEC-18    2345     2
```

As you can see i have multiple years and i need the partition on id and year NOT MONTH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a `case` expression in `count` window function.

```
select t.*,count(case when sales is null then 1 end) over(partition by id) as null_cnt_per_id
from tbl t
```

Comment: Sorry I just edited my question . How do we tackle when we have multiple years

Comment: it is unfair to change the question after it has been answered..i'd suggest you put in some effort into trying out the extension to the question you just posted..`year` part of date should go into `partition by`.

Comment: Agreed.. you have answered my question already and you deserve credit for this. I have accepted your answer. However. I have tried this and didn't appear to work  count(case when sales is null then 1 end) over(partition by id,extract(year from reportdate )) as null_cnt_per_id_year ..Any thoughts please